# Ionic 2 builded application (IOS, Android) slow at boot up

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am building a app using ionic 2, angular 2 and typescript.

Currently, the released application(IOS & Android) boot up time very slow at the mobile devices.

Even the start template with some UI need to load 5 seconds at iPhone 6, 6 second on oneplus 3. This speed too slow and can't accept. My app is more complicated that takes like 10 second to boot to a front page.

My code to start the app.

```
ionic start test --v2 --ts
```

Can the boot time improved to a acceptable level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ionic 2 new `RC4` changed the building process. Now app can be built with AoT using

```
ionic run android --prod
```

For more info check out this [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6776) on `ionic`

**Edit**

`Ionic-cli` 3 further modularize it and cordova commands needs `ionic cordova`. so you need to run it like

`ionic cordova run android --prod`

Comment: For newer ionic versions, it is ```ionic cordova run android --prod```